# Cookie cant be read even cookie is present

Tags: hooks, cookies

```
add_action( 'wp', 'setCookies', 10);
```

I am using this hook to set cookies. I am using 'wp' because I need to get the current post ID.

Now on my sidebar.php, I am calling `if(isset($_COOKIE['cookiename']))` but it returns nothing.

I checked on chrome devtools and `cookiename = postID` is exisiting there.

When I refresh the page or go to another page, the cookie is now returning something.

So I'm guessing maybe my cookie is being set only after the sidebar.php is loaded?
If so, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

The $_COOKIE array contains only these cookies that came in the request from the browser.

setcookie() adds an HTTP header asking the client to send the cookie during subsequent requests.

So yeah - you can’t access $_COOKIE in the same request it is set.